# Bokeh - How to Click and Drag?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to click-and-drag the scatter points the points of a bokeh scatter plot. Any ideas how to do this?

(edit: this is [an example](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/drag_points.html) of what I'd like to do)

For an example of a scatter, the code below generates the scatter plot chart found half-way through [this page](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/intro.html).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# create a Figure object
p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools="pan,reset,save")

# add a Circle renderer to this figure
p.circle([1, 2.5, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1, 1.5], radius=0.3, alpha=0.5)

# specify how to output the plot(s)
output_file("foo.html")

# display the figure
show(p)
```

Comment: As a comment to my own question: I am studying the documentation in order to use Bokeh to develop the interactive charts and widgets of a Flask app, and I find the bokeh-server documentation a bit ***thin*** (e.g. missing widgets and dashboard here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#widgets-and-dashboards). 

Yet studying alternatives for this project I saw I am not the only one seeking "a web version of pyqt", and bokeh seems to offer a number of interesting widgets. It would be great to bring the docs of the library in line with the likes of matplotlib.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? This is a must-have feature for me so my potential use of Bokeh depends on it.

Comment: Currently, there are JS callbacks that can be attached to events on bokeh objects, but nothing on dragging.

Comment: This is a very recent feature addition to Bokeh, it did not exist for most of the past 3 years. I have added an answer using the new tools below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multi-gesture edit tools are only a recent addition, [landing in version 0.12.14](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2018/2/7/release-0-12-14/). You can find much more information in the [Edit Tools](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#edit-tools) section of the User's Guide.

Specifically to be able to move points as described in the OP, use the [`PointDrawTool`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#pointdrawtool):

[image]

Here is a complete example you can run that also has a data table showing the updated coordinates of the glyphs as they are moved (you will need to activate the tool in the toolbar first, it is off by default):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, Column
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource

output_file("tools_point_draw.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[],
           title='Point Draw Tool')
p.background_fill_color = 'lightgrey'

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [1, 5, 9], 'y': [1, 5, 9], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
})

renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)
columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]
table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='black')
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Column(p, table))
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement this using CustomJS? I want to fully control how the user interacts with the plots. - I would basically would like to customize the logic of how points are added, removed and dragged.

Comment: For that level of customization you are looking at a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html). For reference, see the [Python side definition of `PointDrawTool`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/models/tools.py#L954) and the [corresponding JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/tools/edit/point_draw_tool.ts)

Comment: I guess I'd add that it *might* be possible to do something similar using [`CustomJS` together with `bokeh.events`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-user-interaction-events) but I think it at this level of complexity a custom extension would be more robust.

Comment: How can one do a similar logic for different Bokeh figures in a layout? Practically, I want to customize my dashboard grid (layout) by dragging and dropping different Bokeh charts

Comment: That's the province of a DnD web/gui framework, that you would embed Bokeh plots in to elements of. Reinventing that wheel inside Bokeh would be a huge pain, I imagine.